# Run A Procedure or a Function on Every New Insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way so that in a `CREATE TABLE table ( ... )` I can force a procedure or a function to run on every insert?

```
-- For exmaple:
CREATE TABLE table (
  ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Pass varchar(200) -- Can I do Proc(Pass) to return the output instead?
)
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

You can run a trigger on every new insert and do what you want..You have access to virtual table called `inserted` inside trigger which contains inserted values

```
Create trigger name
on tbl
after insert 
as
begin

 ---select * from inserted
--your proc here
end
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, changes in `inserted` are mirrored into the *actual* table, right?
 
So if my proc actually picked a column value and changed that value in `inserted` I should expect the change to be on the original, not just the virtual, table. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You might also take a look at [computed columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). They are virtual columns in a table computed by an expression defined when the table is created. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE products
             (id INT,
              price MONEY,
              tax AS price * .15);
```

-- the column tax is computed as 15% of the price whenever a price is changed (inserts or updates). Though having limitations they come in handy in simple cases.